# Is there a way to keep keyboard focus?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield

I have a TextField widget to add players in a List. But I want the keyboard to stay focus when I add players, and on submit, my keyboard keeps loosing focus.. Any Idea ?

Here is my TextField widget:

```dart
TextField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          onChanged: (val) => playerName = val.trim(),
          onSubmitted: (val) {
            if (playerName != null && playerName != '') {
              Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context, listen: false).addPlayer(playerName);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            }
          },
          maxLength: 19,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_hint'),
              fillColor: Colors.white),
        )
```

By the way, the `autofocus: true` works but it kinda unFocus the keyboard and give the focus back instantly... So it's not nice to watch. So If you have another idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try using FocusNode.

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Define the focus node. To manage the lifecycle, create the FocusNode in
  // the initState method, and clean it up in the dispose method.
  FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    myFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          onChanged: (val) => playerName = val.trim(),
          onSubmitted: (val) {
            if (playerName != null && playerName != '') {
              Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context, listen: false).addPlayer(playerName);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            }
            myFocusNode.requestFocus();
          },
          maxLength: 19,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_hint'),
              fillColor: Colors.white),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine. I've even put the "myFocusNode.requestFocus();" inside the if and put a else with a "myFocusNode.unfocus();" so that if I really finished adding player, we lose the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can go with FocusNode.
But I have a workaround for this.
I usually set the
`autovalidate:true`
and in validator always return some text.
So whenever the user clicks on the textfield it never loses the focus.
Thus the flutter always keeps the focus on the text field.
But for this, you've to use TextFormField.

But the correct way is to go with FocusNode.
Here's the Code.

```
TextFormField (
autovalidate : true
              validator: (value) {
                return '';
              },
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              onChanged: (val) => playerName = val.trim(),
              onSaved: (val) {
               

             if (playerName != null && playerName != '') {
               Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context, listen: false).addPlayer(playerName);
                HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
              }
              },
              maxLength: 19,
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  counterText: "",
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
               hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_hint'),
                  fillColor: Colors.white),
            )
```

and then you can use this to call the onSaved method

```
_formKey.currentState.save(); // And it will call the onSaved method
```

Here the _formKey

```
Form(
    key: _formKey,
child: Widget(),
),
```

Wrap the whole widget tree where your textformfield is present.

Comment: I'm sure this works fine but I don't want a solution with a TextFormField... I just want a TextField. Thanks !